# spring jdbc update method does not commit the update as get Record returns old value

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-jdbc

I am using spring Jdbc for Database operation with postgres db.

I get continuous notification which I am processing.

1. Event new Call: I insert the new record in the DB
2. Event call Lost : I update the call Lost status in the DB for the same record.
3. Event call completed : I update the completed status in the DB for the same record.

During the step 3 above I get the record from DB where I expect call Lost to be true, but I don't get the updated value which I am doing at step 2.

Note: the events are sent by the single thread who is pushing the events. So all the events are coming sequentially.

```
public void processEvent(EventData event){
    if(event.new){
      dao.add(entity)
    }else if(event.ISLOST){
       entity = dao.getEventById(event.id);
       entity.setLost(true);  // setting isLost to true
       dao.update(entity);
    }else if(event.COMPLETED){
         entity = dao.getEventById(event.id);
         logger.info("is Lost:"+ event.isLost()) // it returns false. Viz its set to true in stp2
         dao.update(entity); //error as isLost is overwritten here.
    }
```

}

DAO code:

```
@Override
public long registerEvent(final Event callEvent) {
    KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
    int row = getJdbcTemplate().update(new PreparedStatementCreator() {
        @Override
        public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection connection)
                throws SQLException {
            PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(QueryDefinitions.REGISTER_EVENT_QUERY,Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            ps.setLong(1,callEvent.getCategoryID());
            ps.setBoolean(2,callEvent.isLost() );
            ps.setBoolean(3,callEvent.isCompleted() );
            return ps;
        }
    },keyHolder);
    long generatedRowId = (long)keyHolder.getKeys().get("callregisterid");
    return generatedRowId;
}
```

Other observations:

1. When I check from Postgres admin during the debug just after dao
   updating the record in DB. I see that the record is updated properly
   but in step 3 its not reflecting.
2. For testing purpose. I also put some delay after updating the record
   in step2 but I still get isLost = false
3. The third event is coming after few milisecond of second event.

Question:
Can you please suggest what could be wrong here?

Comment: We would need to know what the DAO code is, how you handle transactions, where they are started and committed, whether these three calls are made in the same transaction or not, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't commit when you insert into database, so your select will get the old data, because the last transaction was not commit.